# How to get the last dir from a path in a string

Tags: php

I am trying to get the last folder name from a path that i store in a string.

**e.g:** `Home/new_folder/test`

```
result = test
```

Comment: Thank you everyone ;) everyone is correct

Comment: you should accept an answer. Maybe the first one that solved your problem or one that added important/useful information while providing the correct answer.

Comment: Done it, BTW its you thank you again

Comment: A regex would look like `\/[^\/]+$`

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Use [basename](http://php.net/basename)

```
basename('Home/new_folder/test');
// output: test
```

As a side note to those who answered explode:

To get the trailing name component of a path you should use **basename**! 
In case your path is something like `$str = "this/is/something/"` the `end(explode($str));` combo will fail.

Comment: The problem with this answer is when using clean url's (without a script extension) - the last item is a script NOT the last folder.Check my sugested solution...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40456931/622864

The problem with this answer is that it needs a labor intensive specific path as an argument. (I'm lazy, this just isn't going to work for me.)

Ash, solved one problem. (But it is messy. And basename, not explode is the right tool. So close Ash501.)

One liner, dynamic, portable, usually correct, & already packaged in a function for you. You're welcome.

Comment: If you have a full path to file like `/home/test/some_file.php`  and  you need  directory name `test` of this file use `basename( dirname( '/home/test/some_file.php') );` Thank you for ideas.

Answer (score 22):

You can use [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function:

```
$last = basename("Home/new_folder/test");
```

Comment: +1 for not using string manipulation, and for using the right tool for the job

Answer (score 9):

You can use pathinfo - [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$pathinfo = pathinfo('dir/path', PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
$pathinfo = array_filter( explode('/', $pathinfo) );

$result = array_pop($pathinfo);
```

This will also make sure that a trailing slash doesn't mean a blank string is returned.

Answer (score 5):

Explode turns the string into an array, you can then choose the last value in that array to be your result.

```
$result = end((explode('/', $path)));
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
echo basename(dirname(__FILE__));
```

or this

```
echo basename(dirname(__DIR__));
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old question, but this automatically gets the last folder without confusing the last item on the list - that could be the script - and not the actual last folder.

```
$url = pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
$url_var = explode('/' , $url);
$last_folder = end($url_var);
```

Comment: The accepted answer provides a better approach. But if you must use explode your can use `explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $url);` to make it windows/linux compatible.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
$baseUrl=basename('/path/to/site');
echo $baseUrl;
```

Incase your URL has `'/'` at the end you can do:

```
$url_to_array = parse_url('/path/to/site/');
$baseUrl = basename($url_to_array['path']);
echo $baseUrl;`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$directory = 'Home/new_folder/test';
$path = explode('/',$directory);
$lastDir = array_pop($path);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$path = explode('/', $yourPathVar);
// array_pop gives you the last element of an array()
$last = array_pop($path);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you want something dynamic that will work most of the time as is-- maybe a reusable function or something.

Get the URI from the data the webserver gave you in the request via the $_SERVER data: $_SERVER('REQUEST_URI')

From that URI, get the path: parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH))

basename() is the right tool to get the last directory once you've distilled a path from the full URI: basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH))

```
function lastPathDir() {
    // get a URI, parse the path from it, get the last directory, & spit it out 
    return basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
}
```

Comment: When writing it, I already saw one problem that could pop up. Front end mumbo jumbo one way or another may get a little crazy and possibly feed a URL that you may not have been expecting.

Comment: Also, the OP wants to process a path, not a URL.

Answer (score 0):

This works on windows environtment too, and also works if the path given ends with a slash.

```
function path_lastdir($p) {
    $p=str_replace('\\','/',trim($p));
    if (substr($p,-1)=='/') $p=substr($p,0,-1);
    $a=explode('/', $p);
    return array_pop($a);
}
```