# How can I get the name of the current directory - not the whole path?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the last dir from a path in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733851/how-to-get-the-last-dir-from-a-path-in-a-string)

I'm using `getcwd()` to return something like this: `home/abc123/public_html/blah/myDir`

How can I modify this string to simply return `myDir`?

Comment: Yup, fair enough, I clearly didn't look hard enough!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Either use basename:

```
print basename("home/abc123/public_html/blah/myDir");
//Output: myDir
```

Or `strpos` and `substr`:

```
$fullPath = "home/abc123/public_html/blah/myDir";
print substr($fullPath, strrpos($fullPath, "/") + 1);
//Output: myDir
```

Comment: Cheers, that's just what I was looking for.